# To zip a list with more than 2 lists

Tags: python

I have data in this format in a text file. All I want is to covert this content in dictionary within a dictionary data structure

('Marks_Subjects ', "[['Time', 'maths', 'Science', 'english'], ['2013-08-31-16', 100, 50, 65], ['2013-08-31-17', 90, 50, 65], ['2013-08-31-18', 80, 60, 85]]")

I want the output to be like:-

```
{'Marks': {'maths': {'2013-08-31-16': {'Subjects': '100'}},

               'Science':{'2013-08-31-16': {'Subjects': '50'}},

               'maths':{'2013-08-31-16': {'Subjects': '65'}}}
```

and so on for 17:00 and 18:00 too

Here is the code snippet:-

```
import sys
import json
def module2():
    title, data = ('Marks_Subjects ', "[['Time', 'maths', 'Science','english'],['2013-08-31-16', 100, 50, 65], ['2013-08-31-17', 90, 50, 65],['2013-08-31-18', 80, 60, 85]]")
    title, sub_title = title.split('_')
    data = json.loads(data.replace("'", '"'))
    data = dict(zip(*data))
    date = data.pop('Time')
    #for subject, value in data.iteritems():
    print {title: {subject: {date: {sub_title: value}} for subject, value in data.iteritems()}}

module2()
```

I split the title Marks_Subjects so that Marks is my Title and Subjects is my sub_title. json.loads converts a unicode string into a python data structure data.zip maps the indexes of the 2 lists. The problem here is that I am getting this error

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 4; 2 is required
```

I guess this means that the zip function can only zip 2 lists. I want to zip the indexes of first list that is `["Time", "Maths", "Science", "English"]` with the rest of the lists.

So I guess a loop has to be run in order to achieve this. But I need some help doing that.

If I have 2 lists in my 'data' then it works just fine.

Comment: zip(seq1 [, seq2 [...]]) -> [(seq1[0], seq2[0] ...), (...)]

Comment: Can you please make appropriate changes in the code above as I didn really get it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
title, data = ('AssetType_FrameDrops ', "[['Time', 'uploaded', 'Unknown', 'captured'], ['2013-08-31-16', 34885, 0, 943640], ['2013-08-31-17', 19167, 0, 1095645], ['2013-08-31-18', 11610, 0, 1005367], ['2013-08-31-19', 4741, 0, 1318737], ['2013-08-31-20', 5829, 0, 1066768], ['2013-08-31-21', 5748, 0, 946647], ['2013-08-31-22', 55554, 0, 900068], ['2013-08-31-23', 70560, 0, 792410]]") 
key1, key2 = title.split("_")

from ast import literal_eval
data = literal_eval(data)
headers, data = data[0], data[1:]
marks = [dict(zip(headers, items)) for items in data]

result = {}
for current_dict in marks:
    current_time = current_dict["Time"]
    for k, v in current_dict.items():
        if k == "Time": continue
        if k not in result: result[k] = {}
        if current_time not in result[k]: result[k][current_time] = {}
        result[k][current_time][key2] = v

from pprint import pprint
result = {key1: result}
pprint(result)
```

**Output**

```
{'AssetType': {'Unknown': {'2013-08-31-16': {'FrameDrops ': 0},
                           '2013-08-31-17': {'FrameDrops ': 0},
                           '2013-08-31-18': {'FrameDrops ': 0},
                           '2013-08-31-19': {'FrameDrops ': 0},
                           '2013-08-31-20': {'FrameDrops ': 0},
                           '2013-08-31-21': {'FrameDrops ': 0},
                           '2013-08-31-22': {'FrameDrops ': 0},
                           '2013-08-31-23': {'FrameDrops ': 0}},
               'captured': {'2013-08-31-16': {'FrameDrops ': 943640},
                            '2013-08-31-17': {'FrameDrops ': 1095645},
                            '2013-08-31-18': {'FrameDrops ': 1005367},
                            '2013-08-31-19': {'FrameDrops ': 1318737},
                            '2013-08-31-20': {'FrameDrops ': 1066768},
                            '2013-08-31-21': {'FrameDrops ': 946647},
                            '2013-08-31-22': {'FrameDrops ': 900068},
                            '2013-08-31-23': {'FrameDrops ': 792410}},
               'uploaded': {'2013-08-31-16': {'FrameDrops ': 34885},
                            '2013-08-31-17': {'FrameDrops ': 19167},
                            '2013-08-31-18': {'FrameDrops ': 11610},
                            '2013-08-31-19': {'FrameDrops ': 4741},
                            '2013-08-31-20': {'FrameDrops ': 5829},
                            '2013-08-31-21': {'FrameDrops ': 5748},
                            '2013-08-31-22': {'FrameDrops ': 55554},
                            '2013-08-31-23': {'FrameDrops ': 70560}}}}
```

Comment: It giving me the following error:-  current_time =current_dict["Time"]
KeyError: 'Time'

Comment: ('AssetType_FrameDrops ', "[['Time', 'uploaded', 'Unknown', 'captured'], ['2013-08-31-16', 34885, 0, 943640], ['2013-08-31-17', 19167, 0, 1095645], ['2013-08-31-18', 11610, 0, 1005367], ['2013-08-31-19', 4741, 0, 1318737], ['2013-08-31-20', 5829, 0, 1066768], ['2013-08-31-21', 5748, 0, 946647], ['2013-08-31-22', 55554, 0, 900068], ['2013-08-31-23', 70560, 0, 792410]]")

Comment: This is the real content in my text file. This marks, subjects is just an example

Comment: @aman Please check the updated answer with the result for your actual input.

Comment: So title, data = ('AssetType_FrameDrops ', "[['Time', 'uploaded', 'Unknown', 'captured'], ['2013-08-31-16', 34885, 0, 943640], ['2013-08-31-17', 19167, 0, 1095645], ['2013-08-31-18', 11610, 0, 1005367], ['2013-08-31-19', 4741, 0, 1318737], ['2013-08-31-20', 5829, 0, 1066768], ['2013-08-31-21', 5748, 0, 946647], ['2013-08-31-22', 55554, 0, 900068], ['2013-08-31-23', 70560, 0, 792410]]")

Comment: @aman Correct. If that fixes the problem, please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Only the output is updated, and it should be AssetType instead of Makrs and FrameDrops instead of Subjects. Have you updated the solution too that you provided because It seems exactly the same to the original one you provided

Comment: Can I ask you one more question?